# How can filter some multiline statement in vim

Tags: regex, vim, vim-plugin

I have vim-script function call `ScreenShellSend("some string")` and I would like to be able to filter multiple lines to feed this function with a correct string.

How can I go from, for example, this:

```
//@brief: an example => TO LINE IS REMOVED
anExampleOfFunction:{[x;y]
    x: doing some stuff; //a comment => after // is removed
    //a comment => this is removed
    :y;
 };
 someVariable: 5;
 //another comment => this is removed
 anotherFunction:{[x] 2*x};
```

To:

```
anExampleOfFunction:{[x;y] x: doing some stuff; :y; }; someVariable: 5; anotherFunction:{[x] 2*x};
```

Comment: Rather than giving  your mapping or command alone, you can also add example for original and expected text. So, that it will be easy for me to understand what you wanted to do and answer for it

Comment: You can go to each line and press `f/` to find a comment and then press `df$` to delete til end. Then press J to join that with next line. Pressing 3J will join current line with next two lines,for example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following `substitute` command to achieve your goal:

```
:%s`\(//.\+\)\?\n``
```

This removes comments and newlines.

For your example, it will give you the following result:

```
anExampleOfFunction:{[x;y]    x: doing some stuff;         :y; }; someVariable: 5;  anotherFunction:{[x] 2*x};
```

**Edit:**

Here is a function that does the same (except it will work with its argument instead):

```
function! Format(lines)
    let lines = []
    for line in a:lines
        let new_line = substitute(line, '//.*', '', '')
        call add(lines, new_line)
    endfor
    return join(lines)
endfunction
```

Comment: Ok but it is not exactly what I ask, I want a vim-script function so basically the function I'll call in the script like: `your_function(getline("'<", "'>"))`. It might be trivial but I do not know anything about vim scripts, so that's why I'm bountying

Comment: I edited my answer to include a function that works as you requested.